# What's the difference between Processing and Processing.JS

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I'm confused... What's the difference between Processing and PJS?

Are they the same or what?

Comment: Move your mouse over the blue "processing" and "processing.js" boxes under your question. Click on the "info" links.

Answer (score 4):

Think about it this way:

- "Core Processing" contains [all of the variables and functions](https://www.processing.org/reference/) you can use in a plain old Processing sketch.
- You can deploy "core Processing" as a Java application. If you do so, you can also use Java libraries, like minim.
- You can also deploy "core Processing" as JavaScript using Processing.js. If you do so, you can embed your sketch into a webpage and use JavaScript syntax to access the html components of that surrounding webpage.
- But you can't mix them: you can't embed a Java application in a webpage (applets are dead), and you can't use Java libraries in a JavaScript webpage.